# The steps for applying to PostDoc positions

Tags: phd, research-process, application, postdocs, job

I have a PhD in computer science and recently I would like to get a postdoc with a respectful professor in my field to update my research works, or after that working in more applied domains in companies.

I don't know the steps of applying for postdoc positions specially in USA and Canada.

I'm a non-native English speaker. Furthermore, I have several important concerns as,

- How long does it take the process of applying?
- the range of scholarship for PostDoc job
- The general requirement for postdoc applicant (number of publications, teaching experience and etc)
- The possibility of research working before the acceptance

  I'd like to see the comments based on these concerns and also to know the real experiences of PostDoc applying.

Comment: Although I like this question, isn't this too broad and has too many good answers?

Comment: The bullets that you have added to refine this question are helpful, but it is still too broad.  It would be better if you can focus on one bullet in this question, and ask the others as separate questions.  I believe that some of your questions have also been answered elsewhere on the site, if you search for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try to approach the best professors in your field and ask them to visit their lab (and most probably they will ask you to make a talk where you present your PhD). It is a hasle to prepare a talk in a prestigious lab, but then you let yourself known, and when a position comes up there you might learn about it first and who knows. 
I would try to contact people I would really want to work with and see what comes next.